# Run Python file with relative path outside current folder in Jupyter Notebook

Tags: python, path, jupyter-notebook, jupyter

Let's say I have the python file `~/file_to_run.py` that I want to run from jupyter notebook (`~/notebooks/my_notebook.ipynb`) using the magic command `%run`. The problem is that `file_to_run.py` uses a relative path for example:

```
open('data/file.csv') # full path ~/data/file.csv
```

When I run `~/file_to_run.py` from `~/notebooks/my_notebook.ipynb` with:

```
%run ../file_to_run.py
```

I get the following error:

```
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'data/file.csv'
```

Is the any fix without modifying the python file? Thank you!

Comment: where is the data folder?

Comment: @FloLie ~/data/file.csv the same folder as python file.

Comment: is it feasible to use ```os.path.join(os.path.realpath(__file__),'data/file.csv')``` there?

Comment: Basically ```os.path.realpath(__file__)``` returns the path of the current file, in your case ```~``` and then concats the relative piece to it

Answer (score 2):

Changing the working directory could be a solution:

```py
import os
os.chdir('../') # Change the working directory
%run file_to_run.py # Call the script from new working directory
```

Comment: Thank you! What `os` function can I use to print the current dir? And how can I change it back?

Comment: You're welcome, I think you can use ```print(os.getcwd())```